# Calculate colors from red to green

Tags: java, colors

I want to calculate colors from red to green. But in fact my code calculates the colors from red to yellow. What I am doing wrong?

```
package test;

public class Fader {
    private final int ar,ag,ab,br,bg,bb;

    public Fader(String a, String b) {

        int ac = Integer.decode(a.replaceAll("^#", "0x").toLowerCase());
        this.ar = (ac >> 16) & 0xFF;
        this.ag = (ac >> 8) & 0xFF;
        this.ab = (ac >> 0) & 0xFF;

        int bc = Integer.decode(b.replaceAll("^#", "0x").toLowerCase());
        this.br = (bc >> 16) & 0xFF;
        this.bg = (bc >> 8) & 0xFF;
        this.bb = (bc >> 0) & 0xFF;
    }


    public String interpolate(float t) {
        int r = Math.round(ar + br * t);
        int g = Math.round(ag + bg * t);
        int b = Math.round(ab + bb * t);

        return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Fader fader = new Fader("#FF0000", "#00FF00");
        for (float f=0;f<=1;f+=0.2) {
            System.out.println(fader.interpolate(f));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpolate function isn't correct.
If you use 1.0 as value it just adds red and green.
Try this code:

```
public String interpolate(float t) {
    int r = Math.round(ar * (1 - t) + br * t);
    int g = Math.round(ag * (1 - t) + bg * t);
    int b = Math.round(ab * (1 - t) + bb * t);

    return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
}
```